# How to check my content file json is true in json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have json files of 7 GB in size, and 110.000 json structure.

I want to check structure content json is valid or not, last I check with jQuery and result failed.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.getJSON( "bismillah.json", function( data ) {
console.log("data exists");
console.log(data);
});
console.log("done command");
</script>
```

but when I am trying 3 files and size 384kb, it succeeds with that code. That's mean (code not error)..

a both I generate with sh and no error in linux

```html
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
declare -a jsons
jsons=(*.json) # ${jsons[@]} now contains the list of files to concatenate
echo '[' > /ext/biar_cepet/json_merge.json
if [ ${#jsons[@]} -gt 0 ]; then # if the list is not empty

  cat "${jsons[0]}" >>/ext/biar_cepet/json_merge.json # concatenate the first file to the manifest...
    unset 'jsons[0]'
echo "${jsons[0]}"
 # and remove it from the list
  for f in "${jsons[@]}"; do         # iterate over the array
         echo "," >>/ext/biar_cepet/json_merge.json
         cat "$f" >>/ext/biar_cepet/json_merge.json
done
fi
echo ']' >>/ext/biar_cepet/json_merge.json
```

i try open with jsonviewer, notepad++, sublime, notepad, mozilla and chrome,,...
all failed

how to check my file is fine?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xr1GBkiLuGQd4ghnPHV0fW-fcKYsbfxY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe it has to do with downloading a 7GB file with 110.000 keys (equivalent to a whole respectable database) into the browser, in one shot? Just saying :)

Comment: can other application split my json file like 7gb become 2 file 3.5gb and 3.5 gb. file become test_1 and test_2?

Comment: Uh, no. Tha't still WAY too big. And I mean _FREAKING WAY too big_. In web development, we're always trying to minimize the amount of data to be downloaded. We minify our files and all. A 300Kb library is considered huge. For instance, jQuery, minified, is 84.9Kb. Servers are usually capped to 2~8MB per call. And you're talking about downloading GIGABYTES of data, I mean, that's beyond Godzilla. Use a database mechanism on your server, I don't know, but you just can't do that.

Comment: how have you ended up with 7GB of JSON? As Jeremy says, that's a crazy file size. I think your real problem is why you're using that file format for such a huge dataset. What do you plan to do with it once you've validated it? Whatever your end goal is, there is almost certainly a better solution for it.

Comment: i just check json data sir and data will be store to clodera

and i success finish cheking :)
thx @JeremyThille for try help
iam using glogg application and can see all 7gb json
and i copy past every 5k structure json to jquery for testing

Comment: "i just check json data" ok but the issue is the use of JSON in the first place. It's not a good solution for this volume of data. Like I said, explain the real purpose of this process and maybe there's a better way

Comment: It's always awesome when someone comes, asks a question, receives strong feedback about problems they have, _and then they argue and reject the feedback_.

Comment: @ADyson actually agree, but that's my boss's request. i dont know how to say him :(. last i say what a feedback said

Comment: If your boss is not able to accept constructive criticism and accept that their approach might be wrong...then it's time for you to get a new job :-)